# Not able to get user by id in nodejs with axios

Tags: node.js, axios, hapi

I am using following code to get user by id ---

```
exports.get = async function(req, resp)  {

 let response = await axios.get('http://localhost/api/collections/get/users?token=abc',{
    "params": {
        user_id: '123'
    }

 });
 return response.data;
}
```

But I am getting all records and not the user with matching id. Even if I put id in url itself as
http://localhost/api/collections/get/users/123?token=abc,  it still gives all the users. How to get user by id?

Comment: Can you post your database query?

Comment: in that case, you have to check the api? what params the api is getting? is it correct? if not, check the client side, if yes, continue checking the api code.

Comment: Please share database query. It seems like the issue is in it

Comment: Show the code for this API.

Comment: using cockpit so there is no model/schema required, I am posting(saving) with the same - axios.post('url', {"data": req.payload}); and it is working fine. There is no database query as such.

Comment: added filter in the url --'http://localhost/api/collections/get/users/token=abc?filter[user_id]=123', now it is working but this is hard code. I need to get user_id from url provided by user (from the browser), stucked with that.